# Java Thread synchronization - Thread.sleep() Method Not Working as desired 

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

i heard, sleep() will lock the current sync method/block
But here, when i call sleep() on thread 1, thread 2 is able to access the same block? Can anyone Explain?

### Main.java

```
public class Main {     
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();
        Thread2 t2 = new Thread2();
        System.out.println("going to start t1");
        t1.start();
        System.out.println("going to start t2");
        t2.start();

    }

}
```

=====================================================================

### Thread1.java

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread{

    public void run() { 
        Syncc s1 = new Syncc();
        s1.me("T1:");
    }   

}
```

=====================================================================

### Thread2.java

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread{

    public void run() { 
        Syncc s2 = new Syncc();
        s2.me("T2:");
    }   
}
```

=====================================================================

### Syncc.java

```
public class Syncc{

    public void me(String s){
        synchronized(this){
        for(int i=0; i<=5; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s+" "+" "+i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

==========================================

### Output:

```
going to start t1
going to start t2
T2:  0
T1:  0
T2:  1
T1:  1
T1:  2
T2:  2
T1:  3
T2:  3
T1:  4
T2:  4
T2:  5
T1:  5
```

BUT according to sleep() method, it should not unlock the current synchronization block right? if so the out put should be..

going to start t1
going to start t2

```
T1:  0
T1:  1
T1:  2
T1:  3
T1:  4
T1:  5
T2:  0
T2:  1
T2:  2
T2:  3
T2:  4
T2:  5
```

i mean after thread 1 execution only thread 2 should start right?
Whats the issue?

Comment: Thread1 and Thread2 are using different instances of Syncc, so they access method me() of 2 different instances of Syncc, so synchronization block doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you have two different instances of `Syncc` in play here. Each thread has its own copy of `Syncc`.

Try doing the same with a single instance. You could also synchronize on the static context and try.

To simulate, modify `Thread1` and `Thread2` to accept an instance of `Syncc`.

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
    private Syncc syncc;

    public Thread1(Syncc syncc) {
        this.syncc = syncc;
    }

    public void run() { 
        this.syncc.me("T1:");
    }   
}
```

You can then start them as so:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Syncc syncc = new Syncc();

    Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(syncc);
    Thread2 t2 = new Thread2(syncc);

    System.out.println("going to start t1");
    t1.start();
    System.out.println("going to start t2");
    t2.start();
}
```

Comment: Got it, really thanks lotz adarshr.
Now am good to go, thanks again.

Comment: Adarshr can you give how can i call notify() i mean i need to print 1-3 with thread1 then thread1 has to go wait() now thread2 should print all 5 numbers then again thread1 need to print remaining...

Actually am new to threads, i saw lot of examples in the net but lot of confusions, but your explanation is really good i understood the concept, pls do this help thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Rules of Sleep, Yield and Join**

- Sleeping is used to delay execution for a period of time, and no locks are
  released when a thread goes to sleep.
- A sleeping thread is guaranteed to sleep for at least the time specified in
  the argument to the sleep() method (unless it's interrupted), **but there is
  no guarantee as to when the newly awakened thread will actually return to
  running.**
- The sleep() method is a static method that sleeps the currently executing
  thread's state. One thread cannot tell another thread to sleep.
- The setPriority() method is used on Thread objects to give threads
  a priority of between 1 (low) and 10 (high), although priorities are not
  guaranteed, and not all JVMs recognize 10 distinct priority levels—some
  levels may be treated as effectively equal.
- If not explicitly set, a thread's priority will have the same priority as the
  priority of the thread that created it.
- The yield() method may cause a running thread to back out if there are
  runnable threads of the same priority. There is no guarantee that this will
  happen, and there is no guarantee that when the thread backs out there
  will be a different thread selected to run. A thread might yield and then
  immediately reenter the running state.
- The closest thing to a guarantee is that at any given time, when a thread
  is running it will usually not have a lower priority than any thread in the
  runnable state. If a low-priority thread is running when a high-priority thread
  enters runnable, the JVM will usually preempt the running low-priority
  thread and put the high-priority thread in.
- When one thread calls the join() method of another thread, the currently
  running thread will wait until the thread it joins with has completed. Think
  of the join() method as saying, "Hey thread, I want to join on to the end
  of you. Let me know when you're done, so I can enter the runnable state."

[http://www.amazon.com/SCJP-Certified-Programmer-Java-310-065/dp/0071591060](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060)

Answer (score 0):

You have created two Synch objects each object corresponding to one thread . Each object has its own copy of me. Hence when your start each thread, withing the run method the thread is calling its own copy of the function me. Since the two thread act only on their copy this works like a single thread scenario. If you do want to test a multithread scenario then make the method me static(class level method) and apply a class level lock.

**Thread1.java**

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread{

public void run() { 
    Syncc.me("T1:");
}
```

}

**Thread2.java**

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread{

public void run() { 
    Syncc.me("T2:");
}
```

}

**Syncc.java**

```
public class Syncc{

public static void me(String s){
    synchronized(Syncc.class){
    for(int i=0; i<=5; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(s+" "+" "+i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {              
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}
}