# Synchronizing a group of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex

I am writing a program in Java in where I have a `HashMap<String, Deque<Integer>> info;`

My data is a list of Wikipedia pages that were visited with an hour time period, along with a count of how many times each was visited.

```
de Florian_David_Fitz 18
de G%C3%BCnther_Jauch 1
de Gangs_of_New_York 2
de Georg_VI._(Vereinigtes_K%C3%B6nigreich) 7
de Gerry_Rafferty 2
```

This data gets stored in the `HashMap` from above with the page name as key and the `Deque` updated hourly with the number of visits that hour.

I want to have one thread `ThreadRead` that reads input files and stores the info in the `HashMap`. And then one `ThreadCompute` thread for each key in the `HashMap` that consumes the associated `Deque`.

`ThreadRead` needs to lock all `ThreadComputes` while active, then wake them up when finished so the `ThreadComputes` can work concurrently.

If I need a different mutex for each `ThreadCompute` then how can I keep all of them locked while `ThreadRead` works? And how can I wake up all the `ThreadComputes` from `ThreadRead` when is done?

I have used `info` as a lock for `ThreadRead`, and `info.get(key)` for each `ThreadCompute` But it is not working as I expected.

Edit:

I add some code to try to make more clear the problem. This is what I have at the moment:

```
HashMap<String, Deque<Integer>> info;
boolean controlCompute, control Read;


private static class ThreadRead extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        while(controlRead) {
            try {
                read();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void read() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized(info){
            while(count==numThreads){
                for (File file: files){
                    reader.parse(file, info); // Reads the file and store the data in the Hashmap
                    keys=true;
                    while(info.getSizeDeque()>10){ 
                        count=0;
                        info.wait();
                        info.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            }
            controlRead=false;
        }
    }
}


private static class ThreadCompute extends Thread {

    public String key;

    public void run() {
        while(controlCompute) {
            try {
                compute();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void compute() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized(info.get(key)){
            if(count!=numThreads){
                algorithms(); //Here I apply the algorithms to the integers in the deque
                if(controlRead){
                    info.get(key).removeFirst();
                    count++;
                    if(count==numThreads){
                        info.notify();
                        info.get(key).wait();
                    }
                    info.get(key).wait();
                }
                if(info.isEmptyDeque(key)){
                    controlCompute=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the simplest (low-level) way would be to use an `Object` as lock and the `wait` / `notifyAll` mechanism. But there's plenty of higher level ways to do that as well. You should probably post some code.

Comment: Yes, if you post the bare minimum of code needed to reproduce this you are much more likely to be able to get more specific help. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946565/java-thread-synchronization-thread-sleep-method-not-working-as-desired) is a great example.

Comment: Time's up. Voting to close...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock` is good for this kind of problem.  There should be exactly one instance to guard the whole `HashMap`.  The file reader needs to acquire the *write* lock of the `ReadWriteLock` because it wants to modify the map.  The other threads need to each acquire their own *read* lock from the one `ReadWriteLock`.

All your threads must be careful to limit as much as possible the scope in which they hold their locks, so in particular, the file-read thread should acquire the write lock immediately before modifying the map, hold it until all modifications for one entry are complete, then release it.  The other threads don't block each other, so they could in principle hold their locks longer, but doing so will block the file reader.