# On what basis does the JVM assign the threads for tasks? Have provided an example I tried down here

Tags: java, multithreading

//This class contains the task. I do this exercise to understand multithreading. I have tried to get the names of thread inside because I wanted to see how they are being executed i.e., Thread-0 enters the block but when the sleep() method is called Thread-1 goes to sleep first. I am not sure how that happens because if Thread-0 enters first, then Thread-0 must sleep first too correct? Also I have my tasks being executed inside the synchronized block, so until Thread-0 finished execution, how can Thread-1 enter the synchronized block.

I have posted the output below.

```
    class Runner extends Thread {
        private Object obj = new Object();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String[] someValues = { "Arun", "Kumar", "is", "an", "amazing", "person" };
            synchronized (obj) {
                System.out.println("Current thread entering synchronized block is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                for (String getSomeValues : someValues) {
                    System.out.println("Current thread printing the value is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    System.out.print(getSomeValues + " ");
                    try {
                        // Sleep pauses the program.
                        // It also throws InterruptedException so it must be
                        // handled.
                        System.out.println("\nThread BeforeSleep is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        System.out.println("\nThread AfterSleep is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

//The main App class executes the threads.

```
    public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Runner r1 = new Runner();
            // The start() method starts the run method in Runner class.
            r1.start();
            Runner r2 = new Runner();
            r2.start();
        }
    }
```

//Output of the code
//Begin Output

Current thread entering synchronized block is Thread-0
Current thread printing the value is Thread-0
Current thread entering synchronized block is Thread-1
Current thread printing the value is Thread-1
Arun 
Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-1
Arun 
Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-0

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-0

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-1
Current thread printing the value is Thread-0
Kumar Current thread printing the value is Thread-1

Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-0
Kumar 
Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-1

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-0

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-1
Current thread printing the value is Thread-1
Current thread printing the value is Thread-0
is 
Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-1
is 
Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-0

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-1

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-0
Current thread printing the value is Thread-1
Current thread printing the value is Thread-0
an an 
Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-0

Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-1

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-0
Current thread printing the value is Thread-0

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-1
Current thread printing the value is Thread-1
amazing amazing 
Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-1

Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-0

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-1
Current thread printing the value is Thread-1
person 
Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-1

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-0
Current thread printing the value is Thread-0
person 
Thread BeforeSleep is Thread-0

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-1

Thread AfterSleep is Thread-0

//End Output

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out a neat way thanks to [Java Thread synchronization - Thread.sleep() Method Not Working as desired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946565/java-thread-synchronization-thread-sleep-method-not-working-as-desired?rq=1)

I changed my main class to look like this

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        Runner r1 = new Runner(obj);
        // The start() method starts the run method in Runner class.
        r1.start();
        Runner r2 = new Runner(obj);
        r2.start();
    }
}
```

And the Runner class will take the object from the constructor instead of creating a new instance. Hence the Synchronize is more successful.